# multiple group by on same select statement

Tags: sql, sqlite

I have a single sql select statement with the same where clause that i need to present the results using many group by's.  My table has over 100 thousand rows and I do not want to execute the same select statement many times to show the aggregated results differently.  My sql statement is very long but here is a quick example of what I currently am doing:

```
select term, count (loans), avg(days), sum(amt) where purpose = "debt" group by term
select length, count (loans), avg(days), sum(amt) where purpose = "debt" group by length
select funded, count (loans), avg(days), sum(amt) where purpose = "debt" group by funded
...
```

Does anyone know of a way to do the above without having to execute multiple select statements?

I have tried doing the initial query into a temp table and do group by's on that table to save the initial query but that assumes the initial query doesn't contain all rows (the where clause can change based on user input).

Answer (score 1):

It *might* be possible to combine multiple `GROUP BY`s, but this requires that you process the results in your code, and not all aggregate functions are easy to handle.

First, group by multiple fields:

```
SELECT term, length, COUNT(loans), AVG(days), SUM(amt)
FROM MyTable
WHERE purpose = 'debt'
GROUP BY term, length
```

This will result in more groups than you actually want; for example:

```
term length COUNT(loans) AVG(days) SUM(amt)
---- ------ ------------ --------- --------
T1   L1               12       3.4       56
T1   L2                7       8.9       10
T2   L1               23       4.5        6
T2   L2               78       9          1
```

You must then *combine* the records to get the result for your specific group.
For example, to get the same result as `GROUP BY term`, combine all records with the same `term` value:

```
term length COUNT(loans) AVG(days) SUM(amt)
---- ------ ------------ --------- --------
T1   -         12+7 = 19       ??? 56+10=66
T2   -       23+78 = 101       ???  6+1 = 7
```

For the `COUNT` and `SUM` functions, you can simply add the values.
For the `AVG` function, you would need the record count (`COUNT(days)`) to correctly combine them.

---

It might be a better to store the result of the grouping by all fields into a temporary table, and then do an additional `GROUP BY` query for your actual results.
(Again, you need to retain enough information to be able to compute the average correctly.)